# How to improve efficiency on a website with frequent live updates

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, optimization, live

I'm making a website that lets users make post right from the front page. Also on the front page I have a live update of the questions posted. Every question in that live feed has its own little container that contains the title of the post and some other details. When the user clicks on a post a (Bootstrap) modal opens. There you can see the title of the post, post details and a live comment feed. Both the post feed on the front page and the comment feed of every post are updated every 15 seconds(the comment feed starts updating when it's modal is open and when any modal is open the post feed on the front page stops updating). All of the 'live' features are working through jQuery/Ajax. What I have noticed is that even on my local server this takes some noticeable time to load. My database is in MySQL and I have made several(around 15) test posts and added comments to some.

The code for the post feed is basically:

```
function updatePosts({
$("#postContainer").load('post_pull.php');
}
setInterval('updatePosts()', 15000);
```

And the php file just returns all posts within divs, with the details of posts with a modal and some scripts.

The comment feed of each post is quite similar except it pulls the comments that have the 'parent ID' of the opened modal.

So my question is : what is the most efficient way of doing the live updates, because if the loading time is noticeable now, on a local server and with a handfull of posts, it will be unuseable on a real server with people constantly posting.

Comment: how long is `noticeable time to load` ? There are multiple aspects to it...server processing time, transport time and rendering time

Comment: How can I diferentiate the different aspects? The loading time is about 2 seconds on the front page feed

Comment: Is that after initial page load? 2 seconds is a very long time for most ajax

Comment: I run the updatePosts() function on document.ready() and the page prints a console message when page is ready and when the content is loaded. Between those 2 messages there is a little less then 2 seconds of a gap.

Comment: inspect actual requests in dev tools network. Could be some inefficiencies at server if requests are actually taking that long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you require updatePosts() tell the server last ID of your posts currently displayed, so server can send only posts which your page doesnt have.

```
updatePosts(lastID);

function updatePosts(lastid) {
 $.get( "post_pull.php?lastid=" + lastid, function() {
   $("#postContainer").prepend(data); // or append    
 });
}
```

so server will return only new posts and you append them in top of your list.

Comment: Would also require different ajax method than `load()`. Answer isn't very complete

Comment: Yeah...that makes a lot of sense. Never thought of that. Will definitely implement that. Thanks

Comment: What method should be used instead of the load then?

Comment: `load()` will replace all content , if you want to prepend only new content would need to use something like `$.get` and handle response yourself

Comment: Kinda feel stupid now...I use $.post when users post questons and then append that to the top of the feed but I never thought about doing that for the posts feed. Thanks for pointing that out.